# Zurb Foundation CSS not working when replacing CDN to Local

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, frontend

Can anyone tell me why; when I change the following path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dhbhdrzi4tiry.cloudfront.net/cdn/sites/foundation.min.css">
```

to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.min.css">
```

the example portfolio page (https://foundation.zurb.com/templates-previews-sites-f6/portfolio.html) loses all of it's structure, even though the local CSS file exists?

Thanks.

Comment: One of the things could be that the path to the local file is wrong. You sure it's the correct path?

Comment: I am certain that the local file path is correct. I have even checked the error console on Google Chrome. What's strange is that some styles are still working. I can provide two images of before and after if that's helpful? I usually use Bootstrap but I'm converting to Foundation.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: @OvidiuUnguru I have indeed.

Comment: Have you tried type="text/css" ?

Comment: It's loading through the stylesheet 'foundation.min.css', it just seems to have messed all of the page structure?